# My ads are not showing

Tags: android, ads

**Hello guys**...
I have source code for application 
When I change the code of `admob` My ads are not showing.
What's a problem?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8MH41.png)

Comment: Show us some source code and your XML for the adview, The screenshot doesn't help at all

Comment: This question is unclear! What exactly is your error? As @TimothyWinters mentioned, provide us with your work so that we can have a look at it whats the problem. Also provide the Logcat if applicable.

Comment: This is Source Code
Change the ID of admob
You will know what I mean

http://www.mediafire.com/file/q9iuac9j0npyo3h/HDVideoApp.zip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can see, your XML is the problem.  You have a RelativeLayout nested inside of a ConstraintLayout.  This is never a good idea.  The whole point of ConstraintLayout is to be able to make a flat layout tree, instead of nested layouts.  Second, the biggest problem I can see is your FrameLayout has a height of match_parent.  This is going to overlap your adview, and so your ad will never be visible.

So, what I suggest, first, remove the relative layout, then, make constraints so the bottom of your frame doesn't overlap your ad.  I would also change the height to wrap_content, so it will fill the view, but not overlap.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
            android:id="@+id/view">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|snap"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/fragment1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"                
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/adView"/>

        <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
            android:id="@+id/adView"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            ads:adSize="BANNER"
            ads:adUnitId="@string/admob_publisher_id" />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

I didn't take the time to fill in all of the constraints (you have to do some of it for yourself!), but this constraint will get you started.  Learn what the constraints do. It can make for much better layouts that are very flexible.

Comment: You're very welcome!  I hope that this helped, and that you have learned a little something in the process :)